# How do i set specific datetime format when insert NOW() in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime-format

This is my query.

```
UPDATE "standardrcpname"
SET savetime = NOW()
WHERE fdcenable = 1;
```

I want to set save time using `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format.

How do i set specific datetime format?..

Answer (score 3):

A `timestamp` column does **not** have "a format".

Any formatting you see is applied by the program *displaying* this value.

If you want a different format when displaying the values use `to_char(savetime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')` or configure your SQL client to use a different format.